# threading.Condition.wait() is not catching SIGTERM

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements, wait

I have the following code which when executed waits to be interrupted by `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT`. When an object is initialized, it creates a `threading.Condition()` and `acquires()` it! The program then registers the signal handlers where `notify()` and `release()` is called when the above mentioned signals are received. After registering the signal handlers, it calls `wait()` on the condition variable and block.

When I tried to stop the program with `Ctrl-C`, its did not respond. IOW, the `_signal_handler()` method did not get called.

```
# start

from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT
from threading import Condition

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._termination_signal = Condition()
        self._termination_signal.acquire(blocking=0)

    def _signal_handler(self, signum, frame):
        print "Received terminate request - signal = {0}".format(signum)
        del frame
        self._termination_signal.notify()
        self._termination_signal.release()
        return

    def register_and_wait(self):
        signal(SIGINT, self._signal_handler)
        signal(SIGTERM, self._signal_handler)
        signal(SIGQUIT, self._signal_handler)
        print "Waiting to be interrupted!"
        self._termination_signal.wait()      # control blocks here!
        print "Notified!!"

def main():
    a = A()
    a.register_and_wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# end
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is hanging in the signal handler trying to acquire the condition variable's lock. I don't know why, but another option is just to wait for a signal.

```
from signal import pause, signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._signum = 0

    def _signal_handler(self, signum, frame):
        print "Received terminate request - signal = {0}".format(signum)
        self._signum = signum
        return

    def wait_for_signal(self):
        signal(SIGINT, self._signal_handler)
        signal(SIGTERM, self._signal_handler)
        signal(SIGQUIT, self._signal_handler)
        print "Pause until signaled"
        while self._signum == 0:
            pause()

def main():
    a = A()
    a.wait_for_signal()

main()
```

The reason to check for `self._signum` is in case another signal wakes `pause()`. A simple example of that would be `SIGALRM`.

Comment: `signal.pause()` is Unix only, better use some kind of short sleep method like `time.sleep(1.0)` or `threading.Condition.wait(1.0)` for portability.

Comment: @Tey' The purpose of this question is to avoid using `threading.Condition.wait` as it causes this deadlock scenario, even when called with a timeout.